# Disabling Hibernate batch processing

Tags: java, hibernate

In order to debug an issue with our usage of Hibernate, I would like to disable Hibernate's batch insert/update mechanism to use non-batched statements instead.

I know that I can set `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1`, but that still goes through the normal batching code with a batch size of 1.

Is there any way to completely turn off batch processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to avoid calling the PreparedStatement#addBatch(sql) method by Hibernate (and instead use dedicated statement instance for every operation). Unfortunately there is no easy way to do that. But... I have checked the Hibernate source code and it seems that Hibernate checks multiple conditions before running the update/insert operation. It decides wheter to use batch or not. Have a look at the method AbstractEntityPersister#update. There should be a line like this:

```
final boolean useBatch = j == 0 && expectation.canBeBatched() && isBatchable(); //note: updates to joined tables can't be batched...
```

One thing which you can do is to replace isBatchable() method by your own implementation which will always return false. By default it looks like this:

```
public boolean isBatchable() {
        return optimisticLockMode()==Versioning.OPTIMISTIC_LOCK_NONE ||
            ( !isVersioned() && optimisticLockMode()==Versioning.OPTIMISTIC_LOCK_VERSION ) ||
            getFactory().getSettings().isJdbcBatchVersionedData();
    }
```

Therefore you could choose one of the following approaches:

- create your own implementation of EntityPersister
- replace the Hibernate source code
- tweak the configuration by setting the property hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data = false and by setting locking mode for every entity which you have to OPTIMISTIC_LOCK_ALL.

As I said before not simple but possible.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-jdbc-properties):

> hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: A non-zero value enables use of JDBC2 batch
>   updates by Hibernate. e.g. recommended values between 5 and 30

Comment: Well, except for the fact that removing hibernate.jdbc.batch_size or setting hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0 does not disable batching.

Comment: Put a break point in org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createBatcherFactory(Properties, int) to see which value is passed and which batcher factory it uses. Do the same in org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(Properties). Either Hibernate has a bug, or your configuration is not the one you think.

Comment: @Thilo Make sure you have `<property name="order_inserts">true</property>`

Comment: Setting hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0 in hibernate.properties worked well for me. Thanks JB Nizet

Comment: The property is named `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` if you use Spring Boot. Didn't appear to work for me though.